# Where does Magento 2 URL Segment Parsing Happen

Tags: php, module, magento2, mvc

In Magento 2 routing, the system parses the URL segments into three sections

```
module-or-front/segment2/segment3
```

Which specific class file does this happen in?

Put another way, the request object has a `getModuleName` method that looks like this

```
public function getModuleName()
{
    return $this->module;
}
```

Where does Magento 2 get the string that ultimately sets the `module` property?

Comment: @AmitBera Not sure you understood the question -- how would an interface do anything?

Comment: sorry... @alam Storm.... misunderstood your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think everything is set up in `Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base::matchAction`
The line you are looking for is `$request->setModuleName($moduleFrontName);` but I guess you wanted the full method.
This `matchAction` method is called by the `match` method from the same class that is called by `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::dispatch()` ....and so on.

**[EDIT]**
not 100% sure, but I think the actuall splitting of the url is done in `Zend\Uri\Uri::makeRelative()`

```
$pathParts = preg_split('|(/)|', $this->getPath(), null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: I'm looking for the the spot the string in `$moduleFrontName` gets pulled from [probably `$_GET`].